# Embedded Linux and Init problem - Init won't start

Tags: linux, networking, configuration, embedded, init

I'm working on a embedded system. I have multiple SD cards to save copy of Linux rootfs on (kernel saved in nand). On a original SD card, where is located a system, and from this card the system is copied to another - everything works nice. Init service is working as it should.

But there is a problem on copied system on another SD cards - system is working, but it's not turning on init service, where is located for example network, sshd init, needed for a application.

Two things - when I was copying system not all of files wanted to copy (especially from /dev/, but it is normal, beacuse of aim of this files). But maybe another files weren't coppied properly?

Second thing - i'm mounting:

**/var**

**/tmp**

**/var/tmp**

On tmpfs (RAM) - but i think it's not a problem (it's working good on original SD card).

Maybe I shouldn't copy rootfs, and do something else?

Comment: Could you please check file permissions for execution?

Comment: I will check it tommarow.

Comment: Even if running as root, INIT is not working, so it's not a permission problem.

Comment: I checked permissions for /sbin/init and /etc/inittab - both same on original and copied card.

Comment: It's weird - if I have to use respawn to run somewhat. It does not work for about 5 times, but on 6'th (or later) is working. Rest of words (like sysinit, once, boot) not working at all... Pretty weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do some copy/paste things. First, I've downloaded minimal ELDK distribution (i'm using it), copied all with rsync. Next i've rsynced copy of system and copied it on SD card on fresh system. All worked.